# How to auto-cast to concrete interface implementation instance in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am implementing a Flutter plugin and have one question about a design pattern:

Lets say I have an interface like this:

```
abstract class MyInterface{
    factory MyInterface.fromType(MyType type){
        if(type == MyType.first){
            return MyInterfaceImpl1();
        } else if(type == MyType.second){
            return MyInterfaceImpl2();
        } 
        throw ArgumentError('Not a valid type.');
    }
    void hello();
}
```

MyInterfaceImpl1 and 2 are concrete implementations of MyInterface, although MyInterfaceImpl2 has some additional functionality.

```dart
    class MyInterfaceImpl2 implements MyInterface{

         @override
         void hello(){
             throw UnimplementedError();
         }

         void world(){
         }
    }
```

I also have a public and exposed class, which the user has to use, to get a instance of this interface implementation:

```dart
     class MyClass{
         static MyInterface getMyInterface(MyType type) => MyInterface.fromType(type);
     }
```

Is there any way that the user doesn't have to do the cast to MyInterfaceImpl2, when using MyClass like this, to see the additional functionality of MyInterfaceImpl2?

```dart
    (MyClass.getMyInterface(MyType.second) as MyInterfaceImpl2).world(); // the user of the plugin has to do this
    MyClass.getMyInterface(MyType.second).world(); // I want to achieve this
```

Comment: Why don't you just make callers use different constructors for different concrete types, either as constructors on the implementation classes or as `static` methods on the base class?

Comment: I would like to keep it abstract as possible, because there are many different implementations of this interface and then I would need to always add new methods to access the specific type.

Comment: Also, as it is a library, I would prefer to keep the user away of constructing these objects himself

Comment: "I would need to always add new methods to access the specific type." Each added type would require a change to your factory constructor anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to provide a factory constructor (or equivalent) that conditionally returns different types so that the caller doesn't need to do explicit casts on the returned object.  Your approach therefore depends on a runtime argument, but that naturally conflicts with *static* type-safety where the compiler needs to know what the types are statically (at compile-time).

You therefore will need to make a trade-off between static type-safety and dynamic behavior.  Your options:

- Abandon the runtime argument and provide separate constructors (or `static` factory-like methods) for the different classes.  For cases where the argument is known at compile-time anyway, this wouldn't impact callers since there isn't any real difference between calling `MyInterface.fromType(Foo)` and `MyInterface.fromTypeFoo()`.
- Abandon static type-checking.  You could make a `static` method that returns a `dynamic` type, and then callers could invoke any methods they want without needing to perform explicit casts.  Of course, callers could accidentally invoke methods for the wrong type (and accidentally invoke other non-existent methods).
- Make the base class provide a broader interface.  You could make the base class provide all methods provided by all derived classes and throw `UnsupportedError`s for cases where the method isn't applicable.  This provides a bit more static type-safety than using `dynamic`, but it still wouldn't prevent callers from accidentally invoking methods intended for a different derived type.
- Let callers perform explicit runtime casts.  I don't consider this to be any worse than the previous two options since in all of those cases, callers already have the burden of needing to know the runtime type of the returned object.  If anything, this imposes less of a mental burden on callers since it makes it clearer which types support which methods, and runtime checks could need to be done in fewer places.

Answer (score 1):

I used your code and made it like this:

```
abstract class MyInterface {
  factory MyInterface.fromType(MyType type) {
    if (type == MyType.first) {
      return MyInterfaceImpl1();
    } else if (type == MyType.second) {
      return MyInterfaceImpl2();
    }
    throw ArgumentError('Not a valid type.');
  }

  void hello() {
    print("hello");
  }

  void world() {
    print("world ${this.runtimeType}");
  }
}

class MyInterfaceImpl1 implements MyInterface {
  void world() {
    print("world ${this.runtimeType}");
  }

  @override
  void hello() {
    // TODO: implement hello
  }
}

class MyInterfaceImpl2 implements MyInterface {
  void world() {
    print("world ${this.runtimeType}");
  }

  @override
  void hello() {
    // TODO: implement hello
  }
}

class MyClass {
  static MyInterface getMyInterface(MyType type) => MyInterface.fromType(type);
}

enum MyType {
  first,
  second,
}
```

Then by calling the following function I have the same output and have no errors:

```
  void foo() {
    (MyClass.getMyInterface(MyType.second) as MyInterfaceImpl2)
        .world(); // the user of the plugin has to do this
    MyClass.getMyInterface(MyType.second).world(); // I want to achieve this
  }
```

> I/flutter (11245): world MyInterfaceImpl2
>
> I/flutter (11245): world MyInterfaceImpl2